# Stop pointer events while dragging

Tags: javascript

How is it possible to stop pointer events while dragging with pure JavaScript?

```js
let drag = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => drag = false);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => drag = true);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => console.log(drag ? 'drag' : 'click'));


// if drag: add .style.pointer-events = "none";
```

Comment: So,

`document.ondrag = () => {
// disable mouse callbacks ? 
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question but there is an ondrag api already

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event

```
document.ondrag = () => { 
  // disable mouse callbacks  
}
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaanks!